# How to access OpenCart functions from outside the framework?

Tags: php, oop, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have a file located at `opencart_root/myfolder/myfile.php`, which I access via ajax call from **opencart checkout page**.

How to make OpenCart methods (e.g. `cart->getProducts()`), constants (e.g. `DB_HOSTNAME`) and sessions available in `myfile.php`?

OpenCart version is **2.2.0**

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the way it's done with other library classes.  First include your class (I'm assuming you've already done that.  Then pass the `$registry` to it in a constructor method inside **index.php** somewhere after `$registry->set('cart', new Cart($registry));`:

```
$adapter = new Adapter($registry);
```

Now inside your constructor you can set:

```
 $this->cart = $registry->get('cart');
```

And inside class methods:

```
$products = $this->cart->getProducts();
```

This should work up through Opencart 2200 where I believe the class instantiation should be done in `system/framework.php` somewhere after the `// Library Autoload` section.

If you don't want to use a constructor you can also pass `$this->registry` directly to class methods.

Comment: >  First include your class - sorry I'm a little bit unclear as to where do you mean I should include it?

Comment: you can include it however you want where appropriate.  it really depends on how you're using it - i assume you have at least basic knowledge of how to include a php file using `include`, `require`, etc

Comment: I'm weak in oop. I've tried to play around using your instructions, but I've absolutely failed to get anything to work. I'm willing to award you 100 reps if you help me to get it to work. Here's the library I'm trying to integrate with my OpenCart 2.2.0: https://github.com/ddelivery/clientsdk2/archive/master.zip. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @qwaz - How and from are are you calling the new class methods?  A bit of context will help.  Can you give an example in your question of what you've tried?

Comment: @qwaz - looks like i missed you in chat.  feel free to contact me directly via http://zuma-design.com/contact